# I want to delete all files that do not start with the value of any element in an array

Tags: powershell

I have a directory that contain a number of files. In addition I have an array with some strings. What I want to do is to is to delete all files that do **not** start with any of the strings in the array.

So if a have a folder with the following files:

```
test1.txt
test2.txt
test10.txt
dummy.txt
foo.txt
bar.txt
```

And I have an array with the values `'test1','dummy','foo'`.

I want this to result in the following files getting deleted: `test2.txt, bar.txt'`.

If I don't have an array, but only a single item, I got it to work fine like this:

```
Get-ChildItem .\ | where { $_.Name.StartsWith('test1') } | Remove-Item
```

But when I have an array instead of just a string, I'm really not sure what to do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can add a wildcard to your array elements, the following should work:

Delete those matching the pattern in the array:

```
$include=@('test1*','dummy*','foo*')
Get-ChildItem *.* -include $include | Remove-Item
```

Delete those **not** matching the pattern in the array:

```
$include=@('test1*','dummy*','foo*')
Get-ChildItem *.* -exclude $include | Remove-Item
```

Comment: That is close, but I want to delete all files that do **not** match the array. So this basically deletes all the files I want to keep and vice versa. Any way to reverse the filter/include, or wont this approach work with my requirement?

Comment: Change the -Include option to -Exclude

Comment: That worked like a charm. Thanks to @MusaabAl-Okaidi as well for the -exclude parameter.